# wpf MVVM set constructor

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

For example i have window with two columns. In first column i want to show items which have property `IsFavorite = true` in second `IsFavorite = false`. But when i am using SimleIoc container it seems that i coudnot change any parameter's in View. What i need to do create different viewmodel for each view? Or how i can manipulate ListViewModel in another way?

ListViewModel

```
namespace WpfApplication169.ViewModel
{
/// <summary>
/// This class contains properties that a View can data bind to.
/// <para>
/// See http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm
/// </para>
/// </summary>
public class ListViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the ListViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public ObservableCollection<ListStruct> Items { get; set; }
    public ListViewModel()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<ListStruct>();
        Items.Add(new ListStruct { CarName = "Toyota", IsFavorite = true});
        Items.Add(new ListStruct { CarName = "DongFeng", IsFavorite = false });
    }
}   
public class ListStruct
{
    public bool IsFavorite {get;set;}
    public string CarName {get;set;}
}
}
```

MainViewModel

```
namespace WpfApplication169.ViewModel
{
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {

    }
}
}
```

ListViewxaml.cs:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication169.ListView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         DataContext="{Binding Path=ListViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding CarName}"></Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
    <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <view:ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"></view:ListView>
    <view:ListView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></view:ListView>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="IsFavorite"></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="NotFAvorite"></Label>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Also upvote if answer is correct, and if not upvoting then tell what more can be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Tell user control that we want favorite/notfavorite items.
   We do this by adding a public property ShowFavorite to our usercontrol.
2. We need to filter our ItemsSource according to ShowFavorite.
   We do this by applying filtering over original collection. Our ListViewModel doesn't know what is happening.

   ```
   public partial class ListView : UserControl
   {
   public ListView()
   {
       this.InitializeComponent();
   }

   bool _showFavorite;
   public bool ShowFavorite{
       get{return _showFavorite;}
       set{_showFavorite = value;

           if(value == true)
           {
               CollectionView v = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyItemsControl.ItemsSource);
               v.Filter = (i)=>{return ((ListStruct)i).IsFavorite==true;};
               v.Refresh();
           }
           else    
           {
               CollectionView v = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyItemsControl.ItemsSource);
               v.Filter = (i)=>{return ((ListStruct)i).IsFavorite==false;};
               v.Refresh();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

I can't make your code work, so changed it.

```
<UserControl
        x:Class="WpfApp1.ListView"
        ...
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        ...
        >

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModel:ListViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>

<Grid x:Name="MyGrid">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="MyItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding CarName}"></Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>

</UserControl>
```

MainViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public ListViewModel MyListViewModel{get;set;}
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            MyListViewModel = new ListViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class ListViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ListStruct> Items { get; set; }
        public ListViewModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<ListStruct>();
            Items.Add(new ListStruct { CarName = "Toyota", IsFavorite = true});
            Items.Add(new ListStruct { CarName = "DongFeng", IsFavorite = false });
        }   
    }   

    public class ListStruct
    {
        public bool IsFavorite {get;set;}
        public string CarName {get;set;}
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
    <view:ListView x:Name="FavoriteListView" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ShowFavorite="True"></view:ListView>
    <view:ListView x:Name="NotFavoriteListView" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" ShowFavorite="False"></view:ListView>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Content="IsFavorite"></Label>
    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Content="NotFAvorite"></Label>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need 2 new properties for the values you want to return and a bit of linq

```
public ObservableCollection<ListStruct> Items { get; set; }
public ObservableCollection<ListStruct> ItemsWhereFavouriteTrue 
{ 
   get
   {
       return new ObservableCollection<ListStruct>( Items.Where(i=>i.favourite == true).tolist());
   }
}
public ObservableCollection<ListStruct> ItemsWhereFavouriteFalse 
{ 
   get
   {
       return new ObservableCollection<ListStruct>( Items.Where(i=>i.favourite == false).tolist());
   }
}
```

Then you bind the view to these new lists.

Comment: This does not even compile `Items.Where(i=>i.favourite == true)` returns an `IEnumerable<ListStruct>` not `ObservableCollection<ListStruct>`. You need to use the constructor of `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: Your solutions requires to change binding in ListViewxaml.cs. But i want to avoid this. Because in another way i can createn two separet viewmodels.

Comment: If you create two separate view models you would still have to change the binding ?